# Trying to get values from self submit form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a database from which I generate options for the user to select from. Based on this selection, I submit these values to the same page and get the selections using javascript.

In the same form, I have a radio buttons and a multiple selection menu.

The html is generated as such:

Radio button and multiple option selection code:

```
htmlstr+="<select multiple>";
for (i=0; i<g.length;i++) {
        htmlstr+="<option name='ges[]' value='" + g[i] + "'>" + g[i] + "</option>";
}
htmlstr+="</select><br>";
for (i=0; i<st.length;i++) {
    htmlstr+="<input type='radio' name='sts' value='" + st[i] + "'>" + st[i] + "<br>";
}
```

These are both placed within a form, which then has a submit button.
Upon clicking the submit button, I want to know the values of the selections. I understand the multiple selection will be an array, but how do I get the array of values, and I cannot even get the value of the selected radio button. I have already tried getting the value using the `.value` attribute attached to the name, however this does not work.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for server-side code, correct? What framework are you using (C#, MVC, PHP, etc). And what is the url you are posting to?

Comment: That's why I am having trouble.. im not looking for server side code (i can use php if server side), I want to get the selected variables on the same page, so on button click basically

Comment: Ok gotcha. I just added a possible answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a real simple way of doing it. You'll have to check each option.

*There is a HTMLSelectElement.selectedOptions interface that is documented. But it's not used much and I'm not sure of the browser support. Plus, it only applies to the select control and not the radio controls. You can check it out here though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement*

But for a more reliable method, try this...

For the select control, iterate through the selectControl.options array, and check each item for a `selected` attribute. If the `selected` attribute is true, then add that value to your own array.

Pseudocode:

```
  for (var i in select.options) {
    if (select.options[i] && select.options[i].selected) {
      selectedOptions.push(select.options[i].value);
    }
  }
```

For the radio buttons, iterate through the array of objects in the dom (getElementsByName), and check the `checked` attribute. It it is true, add that value to your array.

Pseudocode:

```
  for (var i in radios) {
    if (radios[i] && radios[i].checked) {
      selectedOptions.push(radios[i].value);
    }
  }
```

Here is a full working sample using your code:

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/u890j86j/3/

Comment: Worked perfectly.. did not know about the `.getElementsByName`. Thank you.